# Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized

Tags: java, hibernate, struts2, websphere

I am developing an application using Struts2 and Hibernate and the environment I am  using is DB2 and WAS.

When I deployed the application on Apache Tomcat its running fine . But for WebSphere its giving me the following exceptions.

```
Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException: Filter [struts2]: could not be initialized
```

Comment: Which version of WebSphere are you using? 
Can you list what you have in your lib folder of your war?

Comment: Can you also include the part of the error message below the line you posted that may include the cause of the initialization error?